# Converting HTML page design to responsive

Tags: html, css

I want to convert my webstite to a responsive one. I've added the following line to my HTML code but it didn't work.

```
<meta name=”viewport” content=”width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1″ />
```

Is there an online tool that can convert to responsive website?

Comment: Convert a webpage to be responsive with a tag?? its that easy? What effect where you looking to achieve?

Comment: How I wish it were that easy to convert the whole website into a responsive one with just that!

Comment: Changing your viewport meta-tag doesn't automatically "convert" your website to a responsive website. You will have to take a look at [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/)

Answer (score 3):

Responsive is a bit more than that !

> Is there an online tool that can convert to responsive website?

No, You have to design your website to be responsive, it's not a convert

---

An easy way to start is [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) !

You can get a free starting template here :[initializr](http://www.initializr.com/)

And read :

- http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp
- https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong quotation marks. Change:

```
<meta name=”viewport” content=”width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1″ />
```

To:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless its all % sized it wont help much, you'll need loads of media queries to get it right for all screens/devices etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is not just based on the view port. you will have to go through each container to ensure that they are using responsive styling, which I presume they are not at the minute.

I advise looking at the link below it has some good advice for the Styling to help you make it responsive.

[Some great CSS advice for responsive sites](http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design/)